# Get different rows in two typed DataTables with different schema

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-dataset

How to get all rows from TableA that are not in TableB where the schema of TableA is different to TableB(they are different typed DataTable classes coming from different dbms)?

[image]    [image]

I need all `country`-rows where `country_id` is not in `Country` as `idCountry`.

This does not work because they have a different schema(`src.country` and `dest.Country`are different DataTable-classes):

```
Dim srcNotInDest = src.country.Except(dest.Country)
```

*`src` and `dest` are strong typed DataSets*

Note: **not** necessarily **VB.NET**

I assume that i need to provide an `IEqualityComparer` as second parameter but don't know how. Maybe there is another(faster) approach to identify new rows.

**Background**:

I'm importing tables from a MySQL database into a SQL-Server database. It's sufficient to check only the primary key and not to compare the content of the rows. Although this example table contains only few rows but two tables contain ~100000 rows, hence performance matters on synchronizing source and destination.

Comment: Why you dont do it with Linq, or it will be even better if you write a stored procedure get the result from it, instead of comparing it in code.

Comment: @Deepesh: the tables are not only in different databases but in different dbms(MySQL+SQL-Server)on different servers but it's valid to use the same ID's, because there is no autoincrement in destination tables.

Comment: I think actually i'm looking for the best approach to synchronize a MySQL database with a SQL-Server database with similar but not identical schema(normalizing the data in SQl-Server).

Comment: Tim, then I think Linq is the better choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are different databases, I think you need to retrieve the ids separately and compare them in memory, for example (in C# syntax)

```
    var t1 = (from r in src.country  select r.country_id).ToList();
    var t2 = (from r in dest.Country select r.idCountry).ToList();

    var missing = t1.Except(t2);
```

> performance matters on synchronizing source

If this was a one-off migration process, then even if this routine takes a few seconds that would probably be acceptable. But you mention 'synchronize', so I assumes this isn't a one off, so whether this is acceptable depends on how often it is run.

A quick test on my machine reading 200,000 in one table, 100000 in another (admittedly in the same sql database) and comparing them takes 0.4 seconds. There are, of course, other factors that need to be considered, eg the load placed on the sql server etc.

Comment: Thank you, that would work. But i'm wondering if there is no faster way than adding all IDs of both table into a collection, compare every item in the collection with every item in the other collection, throw the result into a third collection and then find all rows in the source DataTable with matching IDs in this "missing"-collection. Isn't there a way to just compare TableA with TableB and throw away all rows in TableA with `idCountry=country_id` so that i get only the new rows? **Note:** This synchronization will be done at least once per day, maybe every hour.

Comment: Don't think so. The usual method of speeding up such queries to to ensure that the SQL Server is doing the work, but in this case I think that is impossible as the tables are in different dbms. But if you are only going to be running this every hour, does it matter if it only takes a half-a-second. Even if you have 100 tables of this size to check, that is still less than a minute overall.

Comment: One thought. You mention you are **only** looking for new records. If  the id a new record is guaranteed to be higher than all previous ids), is it possible to just look for the records in tableb with ids which are higher than the maximum id in tablea

Comment: That was my first idea and i've already added scalar-queries to get the MaxID of every table. But it seemed too fragile to me, because i wouldn't get it when rows would have been deleted. Apart from that this approach would be less flexible if i later want to check the content to get the differences.