# DataTable row comparison with slightly different schemas in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, datatable

Ok, here's my problem: I have two DataTables. One contains SQL Server data, and one contains SQLite Data. I think this means the schemas are different.

Both of the DataTables have four columns.

The SQL Server DataTable has 15 rows, and the SQLite one has 16 rows.

What I would *like* to do is to use .Except() on them, but that doesn't work. That perplexed me because I did a test (albeit the two DataTables had the same Schema in my test) and it worked like it should. But in my production code it doesn't.

Anyhow, what I **want** to get is the 1 record that is different.

I've tried multiple iterations of .Except() to no avail.

I saw this answer: [Get different rows in two typed DataTables with different schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714038/get-different-rows-in-two-typed-datatables-with-different-schema)
But it doesn't quite seem to be what I want to do.

Comment: do you have any common column between the two datables?

Comment: Yes, but I'm hoping to use this on multiple tables in this program.

Comment: i think, you have two solutions : 1 - ``.Except`` by common column like the answer in you question, 2 - use ``.Except`` by ``IEqualityComparer`` because the two table are reference type, not a primitive type like int, double.... note that in the simple case,  ``tableWith15Recode.Except(tableWith16Recode)`` will gives you empty list. but ``tableWith16Recode.Except(tableWith15Recode)`` will gives you one record.